# Cyclic vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In class we defined what it means that there is a creating element $v$ of a vector space, such that for an endomophism $A$ on $V$ we have:
${\rm span}(v,Av,...,A^{n-1}v)=V$.

Also we said that if the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism is $p^k$ where $k$ is a natural number and $\deg(p)=\dim(V)$ then there exists such an element. Unfortunately, we did not make an example how to find such an element for a given endomorphism. Is there any chance, that someone could give me a hint, how one would try to find such a $v \in V$?

Comment: Something's wrong with your second paragraph. Clearly we have $\dim V= n$ and you need the minimal polynomial to be $p(t)=(t-\lambda)^n$. Your ultimate question is great. Have you tried some $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ examples?

Comment: Oops, not so clearly ... I was assuming $\{v,Av,A^2v,\dots,A^{n-1}v\}$ was a basis for $V$. Clearly we could possibly have $A^k=0$ for some $k<n-1$.

Comment: no we can't, if $A^k=0$ for some $k< n-1$ then the minimal polynomial would not have $deg=n$!

Comment: Right. I added the second remark. Take the case I assumed to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time the question is more clearly posted:

**Claim:** With the notation used in the OP, if $\,A^k=0\;$ but $\;A^m\neq 0\;,\;\forall m<k\,$ , then for $\,v\in V\;s.t.\; A^{k-1}v\neq 0\;,$ , we have that $\;\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{k-1}\}\,$ is linearly independent.

**Proof:** Suppose $\,a_i\in\Bbb F\,$ are s.t. (with $\,A^0=I\,$) :

$$0=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_iA^iv\implies 0=A^{k-1}(0)=A^{k-1}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_iA^iv\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_iA^{k+i-1}v=$$

$$=a_0A^{k-1}v+\underbrace{a_1A^kv+\ldots+a_{k-2}A^{2k-2}v+a_{k-1}A^kv}_{\text{All this is zero}}=a_0A^{k-1}v$$

and since $\,A^{k-1}v\neq 0\;$ we get $\,a_0=0\,$ . So delete the first summand from the first equality above (i.e., begin the sum from $\,i=1\,$ ) and this time apply $\;A^{k-2}\;$ and etc., getting $\,a_i=0\;\;\forall\,i\,\;\;\;\;\;\square$

Comment: so each v that is not an element of the nullspace of $A^{k-1}$ fulfills this. is this correct?

Comment: Yup, just as proved above. Of course, it's easy to see that $\,v\notin\ker A^{k-1}\implies v\notin \ker A^m\;,\;\,m<k\;$